# How to override typescript native interface property with Typescript 2.4

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I found a mistake in the native Typescript interface (for `HTMLTextAreaElement`). There is the current interface for this element:

```
interface HTMLTextAreaElement {
  setSelectionRange(start: number, end: number): void;
}
```

And there what it should be:

```
interface HTMLTextAreaElement {
  setSelectionRange(start?: number, end?: number, direction?: string): void;
}
```

I'm trying to make a quick fix for it. I have put the correct interface to same module I try to use it, but it seems this approach just leads to creating a new interface with the same name. I have also tried to put the following code to the separate file `typings.d.ts` where I have all common typescript declaration, e.g. for importing css files.

```
declare global {
  interface HTMLTextAreaElement {
    setSelectionRange(start?: number, end?: number, direction?: string): void;
  }
}
```

However, it still doesn't work.

I found the problem in the following way. I have an interface that contains this `setSelectionRange` correct variant, and I try to extend both this interface and the `HTMLTextAreaElement` interface by the third interface:

```
interface Test {
  setSelectionRange(start?: number, end?: number, direction?: string): void;
}

interface Extender extends Test, HTMLTextAreaElement {}
```

And then I get the following error:

```
Error: TS2320:Interface 'Extender' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Test' and 'HTMLTextAreaElement'.
Named property 'setSelectionRange' of types 'Test' and 'HTMLTextAreaElement' are not identical.`
```

Actually, this `Extender` interface is a thing I want to make work properly.

What should I do to make this fix? Is it even possible?

**P.S.** I know that it should be fixed by typescript maintainers, but I need a quick fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare it at the top level of a file in the global scope.

```
interface HTMLTextAreaElement {
    setSelectionRange(start?: number, end?: number, direction?: string): void;
}
```

[image]

If you only want the Extender interface to have the method you could do something like this since you can't extend two interfaces that contain the same method.

```
interface Test extends HTMLTextAreaElement {
    setSelectionRange(start?: number, end?: number, direction?: string): void;
}

interface Extender extends Test {

}
```

Comment: if you add my code that contains `interface Extender` declaration after yours, it will throw the same error I have.

Comment: My understanding was that you want to add the extra method to the HTMLTextAreaElement  interface. You do not need the Extender interface for that. Declaring an interface in the same namespace with the same name will result in the interfaces merging.

Comment: Well, I guess I wrote it incorrectly in the question. I want to get `Extender` interface to work, it is an interface where I detected the problem.

Comment: You can't extend two interfaces that have incompatible methods. you could just add the method to the Extender interface.. that seems to work

Comment: interface Extender extends HTMLTextAreaElement {
    setSelectionRange(start?: number, end?: number, direction?: string): void;
}

Comment: Yes, it works, but then if I try to `document.createElement('textarea')`, I have to manually cast it to the `Extender` interface. That's why I try to create global fix to the `HTMLTextAreaElement` itself to make things just work.

Comment: Then the first option using interface merging is what you want.